# How to add a common legend for combined ggplots with grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, ggpubr

I have 4 ggplots and I combined them with grid.arrange. Red is for A and blue is for group B. I want to add a common legend to bottom for them

Here's my code:
`

```
   library(ggplot2)
   library(gridExtra)
   df3 <- read.csv("mydata.csv")

   t1 <- ggplot(data=df3) +
   geom_line(mapping=aes(y=data1_A, x=Time), col="red")+
   geom_line(mapping=aes(y=data1_B, x=Time), col="blue")+
   labs(
   y="",
   title = "data1")

   t2 <- ggplot(data=df3) +
   geom_line(mapping=aes(y=data2_A, x=Time), col="red")+
   geom_line(mapping=aes(y=data2_B, x=Time), col="blue")+
   theme(legend.position="none")+
   labs(
   y="",
   title = "data2")

   t3 <- ggplot(data=df3) +
   geom_line(mapping=aes(y=data3_A, x=Time), col="red")+
   geom_line(mapping=aes(y=data3_B, x=Time), col="blue")+
   theme(legend.position="none")+
   labs(
   y="",
   title = "data3")

   t4 <- ggplot(data=df3) +
   geom_line(mapping=aes(y=data4_A, x=Time), col="red")+
   geom_line(mapping=aes(y=data4_B, x=Time), col="blue")+
   labs(
   y="",
   title = "data4 ")

   grid.arrange(t1,t2,t3,t4, ncol=2)`
```

I also tried with ggarrange by using common.legend = TRUE but I could not.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code is that your single plots don't have a legend. Hence, you will not get a combined legend as there is nothing to combine. Therefore the first step to get a combined legend is to add a legend to each single plot by mapping on the `color` aesthetic and setting your desired colors via `scale_color_manual` instead of setting the colors as parameters. Afterwards you could glue your plots together using `ggpubr::ggarrange` with `common.legend=TRUE` or as a second option use the `patchwork` package.

Note: An even easier option would be to reshape your data to long format which would allow to create your plots with a combined legend and less code by using facetting.

Using a minimal reproducible example base on `ggplot2::economics`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df3 <- economics |>
  dplyr::rename(Time = date, data1_A = psavert, data1_B = uempmed)

t1 <- ggplot(data = df3) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(y = data1_A, x = Time, color = "A")) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(y = data1_B, x = Time, color = "B")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(A = "red", B = "blue")) +
  labs(
    y = "",
    title = "data1"
  )

t2 <- t1 + labs(title = "data2")
t3 <- t1 + labs(title = "data3")
t4 <- t1 + labs(title = "data4")

library(ggpubr)

ggarrange(t1, t2, t3, t4, common.legend = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
library(patchwork)

list(t1, t2, t3, t4) |>
  wrap_plots(ncol = 2) +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]